# Racket Memory usage questionning

Tags: memory, functional-programming, racket

Lately, I have been interested in using Racket for data manipulation and storing.

One thing that keep floating in my mind is it's the data usage when we create a custom parser.

For example this is some code from a [Fosdem 2019 presentation](https://github.com/euhmeuh/fosdem-2019-talk) :

ranch.rkt

```
#lang s-exp workshop/expander

(ranch
  (ponies
    (pony firestorm "Hyaaaaar")
    (pony rarity "I'm so shiiinyyy")
    (pony dash "Look at dat speed!")
    (pony dog "Guys, I'm not a pony.")))
```

expander.rkt

```
#lang racket/base

(provide
  (except-out (all-from-out racket/base) #%module-begin)
  (rename-out [module-begin #%module-begin])
  ranch)

(require
  (for-syntax
     racket/base
     syntax/stx
     syntax/parse))

(define-syntax-rule (module-begin expr)
  (#%module-begin
    (provide the-ranch)
    (define the-ranch expr)))

(define-syntax (ranch stx)
  (syntax-parse stx
    #:datum-literals (ponies pony)
    [(_ (ponies (pony name:id cry:str) ...))
     #'(lambda (pony-name)
         (cond
           [(eq? pony-name 'name) cry] ...
           (else "This pony does not exist!")))]))
```

This will create a data structure for the `ranch`, create a module and modify it afterward to replace the nodes with the lambda `pony-name`.

We can confirm that by checking in the stepper, at the end of the expansion we got :

```
(module ranch workshop/expander
  (#%module-begin
   (module configure-runtime '#%kernel (#%module-begin (#%require racket/runtime-config) (#%app configure (quote #f))))
   (#%provide the-ranch)
   (define-values (the-ranch)
     (lambda (pony-name)
       (if (#%app eq? pony-name 'firestorm)
         (let-values () (quote "Hyaaaaar"))
         (if (#%app eq? pony-name 'rarity)
           (let-values () (quote "I'm so shiiinyyy"))
           (if (#%app eq? pony-name 'dash)
             (let-values () (quote "Look at dat speed!"))
             (if (#%app eq? pony-name 'dog) (let-values () (quote "Guys, I'm not a pony.")) (let-values () (quote "This pony does not exist!"))))))))))
```

Mu question is that, how is this different in memory usage than classic OOP ? If we duplicate the instructions for each data (here the `pony`), doesn't we get as memory usage as OOP when creating class instances ?

Also, would not it be much efficient to have only one function iterating recursively over the nodes, instead of using macro to transform the data into executable instructions ?

I know I have a lot of misunderstanding on functionnal programming, and certainly the practical goal of the code above, I would be happy to understand better what is going here and have your feedbacks :).

---

The link of the FOSDEM presentation https://archive.fosdem.org/2019/schedule/event/makeownlangracket/

Comment: The point was to create a simple domain-specific language that's nice to work with, not to optimize memory usage.

Comment: Memory usage depends heavily on the functionality and how you model it in the core language. In your specific case the result is the binding `the-ranch` that maps pony names to strings. It would be suprising of you could implement the same in OO with less memory footprint or time complexity.